# How to check trigger of a task in Task scheduler using c++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, triggers, taskscheduler

I want to check the triggers for the tasks in the Task scheduler using c++.
I want to use the function **HRESULT get_Type(TASK_TRIGGER_TYPE2 *pType);**
to check whether the task is logon or boot triggered.

```
TASK_STATE taskState;

for (LONG i = 0; i < numTasks; i++)
{
  IRegisteredTask* pRegisteredTask = NULL;
  hr = pTaskCollection->get_Item(_variant_t(i + 1), &pRegisteredTask);

 if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        BSTR taskName = NULL;
                    TASK_TRIGGER_TYPE2 *pType = NULL;
        hr = pRegisteredTask->get_Name(&taskName);               
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
          printf("\nTask Name: %S", taskName);
          SysFreeString(taskName);
          hr = pRegisteredTask->get_Type(*pType);   //Implemented here
          if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
             printf("\n%s",&pType);
          else
             printf("\n\tCannot get the registered task state: %x", hr);
         } 

          hr = pRegisteredTask->get_State(&taskState);
          if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
       printf("\n\tState: %d", taskState);
          else
    printf("\n\tCannot get the registered task state: %x", hr);
        }
        else
        {
    printf("\nCannot get the registered task name: %x", hr);
        }
    pRegisteredTask->Release();
    }
    else
    {
printf("\nCannot get the registered task item at index=%d: %x", i + 1, hr);
    }
}
```

On compilation, it gives me an error saying "IRegisteredTask has no member get_Type()"

Then I altered the code and added
 ITrigger *trig = NULL;
trig->get_Type(&pType);

But that doesnt give me any values either

Comment: What is the problem with the code you show? What is your question? (And no, putting the question in the title is not enough, the title should be a short summary of the problem, and the body of the question should have the actual question.) Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude    I've altered the question. Please have a look at it

Comment: Two things: Are you sure you should use the *dereference operator `*`* when calling `get_Type`? And are you sure that you can print `&pType` as a string? You didn't mix up the two uses?

Comment: On the other hand, [the documentation of `IRegisteredTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/taskschd/nn-taskschd-iregisteredtask) doesn't show it having a `get_Type` function. So even attempting to call this non-existing function is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is code piece works fore me you can have a try:

```
for (LONG i = 0; i < numTasks; i++)
{
    IRegisteredTask* pRegisteredTask = NULL;
    hr = pTaskCollection->get_Item(_variant_t(i + 1), &pRegisteredTask);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        BSTR taskName = NULL;
        hr = pRegisteredTask->get_Name(&taskName);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            printf("\nTask Name: %S", taskName);
            SysFreeString(taskName);

            hr = pRegisteredTask->get_State(&taskState);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                printf("\n\tState: %d", taskState);
            else
                printf("\n\tCannot get the registered task state: %x", hr);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nCannot get the registered task name: %x", hr);
        }

        ITaskDefinition* taskDef = NULL;
        hr = pRegisteredTask->get_Definition(&taskDef);
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            ITriggerCollection* triggers = NULL;
            taskDef->get_Triggers(&triggers);
            LONG trigCnt = 0;
            triggers->get_Count(&trigCnt);

            for (LONG i = 0; i < trigCnt; i++)
            {
                ITrigger* trig = NULL;
                TASK_TRIGGER_TYPE2 pType = TASK_TRIGGER_EVENT;

                triggers->get_Item(_variant_t(i + 1), &trig);
                trig->get_Type(&pType);
                DWORD errCode = GetLastError();
                if(pType != NULL)
                    printf("\nTrigger Type : %d", pType);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nCannot get the registered task definition: %x", hr);
        }

        pRegisteredTask->Release();
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nCannot get the registered task item at index=%d: %x", i + 1, hr);
    }
}
```

Refer to "[Displaying Task Names and States (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/displaying-task-names-and-state--c---)"

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it only displays the triggers without mentioning the name of the tasks. When I tried adding the name in printf(), it gives me an exception.

Comment: @RaisaArief I add getting name part. Please check my update answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/task-scheduler-interfaces), it looks like after you have a IRegisteredTask you need to call get_Definition() to get its ITaskDefinition.

Using the ITaskDefinition, you can get the a ITriggerCollection via get_Triggers()

Then, enumerating over the ITriggerCollection, you can QueryInterface() each ITrigger to see if it supports the ILogonTrigger  or IBootTrigger interfaces.